# recursive function for hierarchically data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

my model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace amief.Models
{
    public class WebsiteModels
{
    public static void getPagesForPage(int pageId, dbDataContext db, List<page> myPages)
    {

        var pages = (from p in db.pages
                           where p.pageParent == pageId
                           select p);
        foreach (var item in pages)
        {
            myPages.Add(item);
            getPagesForPage(item.pageId, db, myPages);
        }
    }
}

}
```

calling the procudure

```
 List<page> myPages = null;

 WebsiteModels.getPagesForPage(0, db,myPages);
```

i'm getting an error

System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

on line "myPages.Add(item);"

I don't understand the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `myPages` to `null` before passing it to `WebsiteModels.getPagesForPage()`. Therefore, the calls to `myPages.Add(item);` in your loop raise a `NullReferenceException` because you can't call a method on a `null` object.

You probably want:

```
List<page> myPages = new List<page>();
WebsiteModels.getPagesForPage(0, db, myPages);
```

Comment: when i remove = null.   i get another error : Error Use of unassigned local variable 'myPages'

Comment: Don't remove `= null`, that only makes your variable `unassigned` (but still `null`). Instead, instantiate a new list of pages as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, "myPages" IS null, so calling a method on it results i a NullReferenceException. You should rather write

```
myPages = new List<page>();
```